# Wrong output when following the filter formula?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make my image sepia, but I get the wrong filter and I cant see why? Is this the incorrect formula of the sepia filter?

```
im = Image.open("some.jpg")
image = np.asarray(im)  
sepia_image = np.empty_like(image)

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        sepia_image[i][j][0] = 0.393*image[i][j][0] + 0.769*image[i][j][1] + 0.189*image[i][j][2]
        sepia_image[i][j][1] = 0.349*image[i][j][0] + 0.686*image[i][j][1] + 0.168*image[i][j][2]
        sepia_image[i][j][2] = 0.272*image[i][j][0] + 0.534*image[i][j][1] + 0.131*image[i][j][2]
        for k in range(image.shape[2]):
            if sepia_image[i][j][k] > 255:
                sepia_image[i][j][k] = 255
sepia_image = sepia_image.astype("uint8")
Image.fromarray(sepia_image).show()
```

The image i get is this

[image]

Comment: What formula? according to what reference? This question is missing a lot of context

Comment: @DeepSpace hello, thank you for the reply. I search up on google what the formula for sepia color is, and I read that we have to find tr,tg and tb. This is done by suming the values of the rgb pixels and multiplying them with those numbers I have done in my code

Comment: Are you using PIL or cv2? I think CV2 is BGR and not RGB which might make your equation wrong. Might wanna look at saturation too possibly (is it fixed to 255?)

Comment: @JasonChia I am using PIL to open the picture and numpy to make it into an array, and i do check in the end that the pixels are 255 max

Comment: Bright pixels seem to have at a very fixed point jump to 0 R and in even brighter places to 0 G as well. Strange behavior, but impossible to debug further without seeing more of the code as well as the source image.

Comment: Is the last `if` supposed to be indented? otherwise it will only check the bottom right pixel

Comment: Please include the necessary imports to make this a complete [MRE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is that your values are going out of bounds.**

For example, using your formula on my example image below, the red channel in the first pixel ends up being `205*0.393 + 206*0.769 + 211*0.189`, which is 278. If you are using unsigned 8-bit integers, this will overflow to 22.

To fix it, you need to use floats and clip the range back to 0 to 255, for example by using this instead of your `np.empty_like()` instantiation:

```
sepia_image = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=float)
```

Then, after running your loops:

```
sepia_image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Then your code works on my image at least.

##### Unsolicited advice: don't use loops

Another issue is the difficulty of debugging code like this. In general, you want to avoid loops over arrays in Python. It's slow, and it tends to require more code. Instead, take advantage of NumPy's elementwise maths. For example, you can use `np.matmul` (or the `@` operator, which does the same thing) like so:

```py
from io import BytesIO

import requests
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Image CC BY-SA Leiju / Wikimedia Commons 
uri = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Neckertal_20150527-6384.jpg/640px-Neckertal_20150527-6384.jpg'
r = requests.get(uri)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

# Turn this PIL Image into a NumPy array.
imarray = np.asarray(img)[..., :3] / 255

# Make a `sepia` multiplier.
sepia = np.array([[0.393, 0.349, 0.272],
                  [0.769, 0.686, 0.534],
                  [0.189, 0.168, 0.131]])

# Compute the result and clip back to 0 to 1.
imarray_sepia = np.clip(imarray @ sepia, 0, 1)
```

This produces:

[image: Sepia version of image CC BY-SA Leiju / Wikimedia Commons]

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for the answer. I should have mentioned that I want to see how it is done in a pythonic way. I have done it in numpy but I really want to see how it actually does the code without a single function

Comment: Then you need to show exactly what are `image` and `sepia_image`. It helps a lot if you provide a **complete** example that others can reproduce. See how I did that, for example. Otherwise it requires a lot of conjecture to understand your problem. (And, by the way, there is nothing unpythonic about NumPy!)